# How to make repeated countdown timer

Tags: java, android

I am making cutdown timer and I wanna reapeat it after break. For example I set timer fo 4 second after this 4 seconds  I wanna have 10 second break and then i wanna have timer again for 4 minutes 
My timer look like that

```
            long millisInput = Long.parseLong(input) * 60000;      
    mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTimerRunning) {
                pauseTimer();
            } else {
               startTimer();
           }

    });
    mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetTimer();
        }
    });
}
private void setTime(long milliseconds) {
    mStartTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
    resetTimer();
    closeKeyboard();
}
private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTimerRunning = true;
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
           updateWatchInterface();
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        if(counter++ < 5){
            startTimer();
        }
     }
  },10000);
        }
    }.start();
    updateWatchInterface();
}
private void pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mTimerRunning = false;
    updateWatchInterface();
}
private void resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = mStartTimeInMillis;
    updateCountDownText();
    updateWatchInterface();
}
private void updateCountDownText() {
    int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted;
    if (hours > 0) {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    } else {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(String.valueOf(counter + 1) +" - "+timeLeftFormatted);
}
private void updateWatchInterface() {
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEditTextInput.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonSet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
    } else {
        mEditTextInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mButtonSet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");

        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < mStartTimeInMillis) {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
private void closeKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("startTimeInMillis", mStartTimeInMillis);
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);

    editor.apply();
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
   }
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mStartTimeInMillis = prefs.getLong("startTimeInMillis", 600000);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", mStartTimeInMillis);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    updateCountDownText();
    updateWatchInterface();

    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateCountDownText();
            updateWatchInterface();
        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

And after set for example one minute I wanna reapeat same time 5 times. (    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this.

```
int timerMilliSecond = 4000;

        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerMilliSecond, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv2.setText("Przygotuj się:\n " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timerMilliSecond = 4 * 60000;
                        countDownTimer.start();
                    }
                },1000);
            }
        }.start();
```

I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: when I put "    countDownTimer.start();" to code all text turns gray. But when i don't put this fragment of your code my app doesnt work \

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int rounded =  (int) (((millisUntilFinished + 999) / 1000 ) * 1000); // 4000,3000,2000,1000 ....
                tv2.setText("Przygotuj się:\n " + (rounded / 1000));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tv2.setText("Przygotuj się:\n " + 0);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(counter++ < 5)
                            countDownTimer.start();
                    }
                },10000);  // repeat after ten seconds.
            }
        }.start();
 }
```

if you don't want endless loop, you should use **counter**. So you can repeat five times.

```
 @Override
 public void onFinish() {
      mTimerRunning = false;
      updateWatchInterface();
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            if(counter++ < 5){
                mTimerRunning = true;
                startTimer();
            }
         }
      },60000);
}
```

Comment: after "countDownTimer.start()" my text becoms gray \

Comment: I tried this code. countDownTimer should be outside of onCreate method.

Comment: It's working but not quite that I mean. Becouse after 10 seconds (i set 10 seconds) Its reapeting but not 10 seconds only 1 second. And reapeating time does not appear on the screen

Comment: Use 10000 not 1000. And you can write the counter what you want.

Comment: Do you know how to make time on the clock show all the time because it works, but I don't renew the screen on which it shows the remaining time

Comment: I didn't understand what do you want exactly.

Comment: Ur code works: after a set period of time i have 10 seconds deleay  andthen i have only 10 second timer not 20 (10 seconds of break and 10 seconds of normal timer) and after 10 seconds (set time) on display i have "00:00"

Comment: I showed you how  you can repeat timer. You can make other changes. You know , your code runs as you wish.

Comment: I tried my answer is working. Now you can edit the code yourself.

Comment: Ok I understand